# Is it possible to have the user manually import a ringtone into my app in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I know that it is not possible to access the ringtones in iOS, but is it possible for the user to import a ringtone into my app for usage? I have read about iTunes file sharing, but I wouldn't want to do that. Is it possible to have the user manually search for their ringtone/audio file on their device and select it (like if I made a file explorer) and add it into my app? Another alternative, could I have it in one of my servers, like say the user uploads it to my server and then the app can have access to it to download and save it to the phone? I am running out of ideas lol. If this is not possible it just looks like I will be scraping this idea and making it an Android only app. I was hoping to make it for both iOS and Android. If it's not possible, what can I do. Any word from the wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option as `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` in AudioToolbox. Check the [documentation here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesPlaySystemSound) I am not sure this can be used to access the ringtones. This should lead you to right direction.

> This function plays a short sound (30 seconds or less in duration).
>   Because sound might play for several seconds, this function is
>   executed asynchronously. To know when a sound has finished playing,
>   call the AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion function to register a
>   callback function.

Not sure whether the usage of this is allowed by Apple, but it looks like it can be used.

Comment: Cool thanks for the tip. Although it seems like I can't do what I want to do legally at least. This will be useful. Thanks.